# How many distinct digit permutations exist for a specific N-digit number?

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic, permutation, number-theory

The problem is simple. We have an *N*-digit digit number (*N <= 18*) and we need to know all the possible distinct combinations of this number. For example the answer for the number 214 (*N = 3*) is  6 (You can create 214, 241, 124, 142, 412, 421). I'm looking for an algorithm that calculates this.

I noticed that  for an *N*-digit number the maximum amount of different numbers is equal to *N!*.
However I have no clue on how this thing works when the digit are not distinct. I tried several methods for example trying to write a formula to make it or code but nothing worked.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see this: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: This isn't homework this is for a project that im trying to do.

Comment: math.stackexchange.com looks more suitable for this question rathen than SO. In geneneral, Number of distinct combinations will be N! divided by number of all permutations of same digits.

Comment: @wohlstad I actually have made some progress on it and now the question is different and the answer is on this platform.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this seems to be more suitable for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be

```
N! / (#0! * #1! * #2! * #3! * #4! * .. * #9!)
```

with `#d` number of `d`.

`N!` is total number of permutation of distinct element.

consider then `1a`, `1b` as disting `1`, we have to divide `N!` by permutation number of `1` (and also for other numbers).

So for `1112235` it would be

`7! / (3! * 2! * 1! * 1!)` (ignoring `0!` which is `1`)

Comment: thanks it helped i would vote but i only have 1 reputation

Comment: Explanation: *[How many different permutations are there of the sequence of letters in "MISSISSIPPI"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1203251/379035)*